# How to send large data to web service?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services

I have a web service and I am sending a large string (approx. size is 700000 characters) as a argument. I am calling this web service from javascript (ScriptManager).

Problem is that when string length is around 100000 it hit web service successfully, but if string length is around 700000 it fails to hit web service and it gives this massage
[image: Error Message]

JS Code

```
MyService.SendData("large string data", function (str) { }, function (err1) { alert(err1.get_exceptionType); });
```

WebService Code

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Test", EnableSession = true)]    
public void SendData(string str)
{//Here is breakpoint.
   //My code
}
```

So my question is how to send large string data to web service?

Comment: Please post your service code. Also, specify the technology used to build the service. Only then can we give you correct suggestion.

Comment: MyService.ASMX is the name of my service so it is ASMX.

Comment: @Learner : I posted service code.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `POST` request instead of `GET`. Data is then appended to the request's body instead of the query string. (You would have to configure your web service to accept `POST` requests)

`GET` is limited by the max length of the query string, and in the case of some versions of IE, this may be 2000 characters.

Comment: can you give me any link for this. I am new to web service. How can I configure web service to accept POST?

Comment: I suggest reading a tutorial on how to use WCF, since ASMX is obsolete

Answer (score 0):

**Few suggestions:**

Increase the “maxQueryStringLength” property in the web.config file as below:

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="2097151"/>
</system.web>
```

Also, if the service is being hosted by IIS, you might want to add the below code in the web.config so that the server does not refuse to accept bigger size XML sent by us:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
     <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxQueryString="2097151"/>
     </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

But, I would suggest you to try consuming web service methods using jQuery instead of plain JS as I think there is something you are not doing right if you are passing the whole message in a URL. Technically, your service must be either `GET` or `POST` call.

A few great tutorials on consuming ASMX web methods using jQuery:
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/97/Cascading-DropDownLists-with-jQuery-and-ASP.NET

Comment: No "maxQueryStringLength" option is there it has "maxRequestLength" and settings its value is not solving problem.

Comment: In that case, you should definitely reconsider your approach.

Comment: I know that it is matter of some setting, so that it can accept large data. But not know where these settings has to be made.

Comment: Again, sending data through URL is not advisable, specially for the webservices. Ultimately, it's up to you how you want to do it. I would still suggest you to go through those 2 tutorials and do it right.

Comment: As in your first link it has saying to use SecriptManager and  I am using this already. So it should be fine.

Comment: No, he is talking about why not use ScriptManager. Read carefully.

Comment: Frome first link "When you register and call a web service through ASP.NET AJAX’s ScriptManager, you may safely enjoy blissful ignorance of these requirements. The framework transparently handles everything for you."

Comment: Here he is talking about third party ajax. I am using asp.net's ajax, not third party.

Comment: Let's forget about what he's talking. Point is, whether you want to send data using URLs or are willing to learn and write the code in a right way.

Comment: If you know this jquery method well then can you write it. It should be easy one.